# Trouble with EventListener in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium

I am having trouble trying to add an Event Listener to my button. Here is what I have in my code.

```
var TabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var Maps = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundImage:'/images/Background2.jpg'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title: 'Maps',
    icon: '/KS_nav_ui.png',
    window: Maps
});
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:'auto',
    contentHeight:'auto',
    top:0,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:false,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:false
});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    height:495,
    width:300
});
var btnInnovations = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:75,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundImage:'/images/Innovations.jpg',
    top:60
});
var btnOaks = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:75,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundImage:'/images/Oaks Campus.jpg',
    top:145
});
var btnWHQ = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:75,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundImage:'/images/WHQ.jpg',
    top:230
});
var btnRiverport = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:75,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundImage:'/images/Riverport.jpg',
    top:315
});
var btnContinuous = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:75,
    width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
    backgroundImage:'/images/Continuous.jpg',
    top:400
});

view.add(btnInnovations);
view.add(btnOaks);
view.add(btnWHQ);
view.add(btnRiverport); 
view.add(btnContinuous);
scrollView.add(view);
Maps.add(scrollView);

TabGroup.addTab(tab1);
TabGroup.open();

btnInnovations.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var InnovationsFloors = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
title: 'Innovations Floors',
url:'InnovationsFloors.js'
});

InnovationsFloors.open({modal : true, backgroundImage:'images/Background1.jpg'});
```

The error I get in the emulator says cannot call method open of undefined and if I take out the Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(InnovationsFloors,{animation:true}); it won't even register the click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you cant have spaces in the name of your Window `url` field, rename your `Innovations Floors.js` file to `InnovationsFloors.js`.

Second part is that the attributes you are passing in to the `open()` command are not supported, it should be `animated` not `animation`, even so, you should not use this in this fashion, [I refer you to the docs on this one.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/openWindowParams)

Instead just do this:

```
Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(InnovationsFloors);
```

Or try this:

```
TabGroup.activeTab.open(InnovationsFloors);
```

If that doesn't work then it means you have not called open on your TabGroup so there is no current tab.

You could also always just try this and open a modal:

```
InnovationsFloors.open({modal : true});
```

Comment: Yeah open modal does work..but later on down when I actually get to showing the image I will need it to open in a new window so that those buttons do not show up in the background. I've seen a tutorial where he uses the Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(); works but for some reason it won't work on mine??

Comment: If your tab group is not open then it wont work, and just give your modal window a opaque background color and those controls wont show behind it.

Comment: But I have my TabGroup.open(); before the event listener? The only thing I can think of was to use containingTab.open because it was used in the template but that didn't work either?

Comment: I ran your code on my box, just replaced the line: `InnovationsFloors.open({modal : true, backgroundImage:'images/Background1.jpg'});
` with `TabGroup.activeTab.open(InnovationsFloors);` and it worked perfectly/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a window with a button try this works for me

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();


//
// create base UI tab and root window
//
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});

var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'I am Window 1',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Hello',
   top: 10,
   width: 100,
   height: 50
});

win1.add(button)
win1.add(label1);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
            title:'New Window',
            backgroundColor:'#fff'
        });
        win.open();
});

tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  

// open tab group
tabGroup.open();
```